# Dynamic Binding conditions Java

Tags: java

My professor has given some information regarding when dynamic binding will occur in java, however after reading many posts on stack overflow and other websites i am not sure if I am getting the right information. My professor states in his lecture notes that dynamic binding is needed when:

1) A variable is declared to have a superclass as its type, and

2)There is more than one possible polymorphic method that could run among the type of the variable and its subclasses

I am unsure about condition 1), as everywhere I have been reading states that dynamic binding is required whenever there is method overriding.
An example:

```
public class Polygon{
    public void getPerimeter(){
        System.out.println("Polygon method")
    }
}

public class Rectangle() extends Polygon{
    public void getPerimeter(){
        System.out.println("Rectangle method")

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Rectangle a = new Rectangle();
    a.getPerimeter();
}
```

Would this code require dynamic binding? Rectangle is not a superclass, so condition 1) is not met. However, the method in Rectangle is overriding the method from the superclass Polygon. How does the compiler know which method to run?

Comment: `Polygon a = new Rectangle();`

Comment: compiler will call the closest method with the object except you call `super` keyword before the method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, *polymorphism* is composed of two aspects:

- **Type inheritance:** using a reference of supertype type to point to an instance of subtype type (ex: `Polygon p = new Rectangle()`).
- **Dynamic binding:** binding the method signature to the method implementation at runtime, based on the actual type of the object (ex: for `p.getPerimeter()`, the `getParamater` method that is the most specific to the actual type of `p` gets invoked).

Since in your example you are not using a superclass type when defining `Rectangle` you are not using polymorphism.

If you want to use polymorphism, refactor your code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // using a supertype reference
    Polygon a = new Rectangle();
    /** 
        there are two methods available here, the one inherited from Polygon and 
        the one Rectangle overrides. Dynamic binding ensures the right method gets 
        picked up at runtime, based on the actual type of the Polygon object 
        (which in this case in Rectangle)
    */
    a.getPerimeter();
}
```

You might argue dynamic binding happens even in your example (since the right implementation gets picked up at runtime), but using it in that manner defeats the purpose of dynamic binding (since if you define the reference as the same type as the actual object, you will always end up with one and only one implementation).

Your professor probably refers to *polymorphism* and not *dynamic binding* though.

Comment: I understand what you are saying regarding polymorphism, however my professor clearly is stating that the two conditions for dynamic binding are the criteria that I mentioned. I am really trying to understand when Java will use dynamic binding. You describe dynamic binding as the binding of method signature to method implementation at runtime, however wouldn't that mean that all method calls would require dynamic binding?

Comment: All non static methods are bound at runtime (or dynamically). Static methods are bound at compile time (or statically).

Comment: Glad I could help!